# macOS going wild with Calendar tasks, what is it doing

Tags: macos, mojave, calendar

When I check the Console for "calendar" I see messages flying by in roughly 1s intervals. What is the system doing I'm wondering? It doesn't exactly look sane.

```
default 09:12:06.088767 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [[CalAgentLinkQueueStatusOperation] operation finished: [0x7fdd5a13e4f0].  Total time in microseconds: [1910] us.]
default 09:12:06.088817 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation removed from connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [YES]]
default 09:12:06.088865 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Removed XPC connection, no remaining operations]
default 09:12:06.088926 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [[CalAgentLinkQueueStatusOperation] operation finished: [0x7fdd57efaea0].  Total time in microseconds: [2374] us.]
default 09:12:06.328268 +0200   AppleSpell  [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Starting operation: [CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]].]
default 09:12:06.328335 +0200   AppleSpell  [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Created new XPC connection]
default 09:12:06.328652 +0200   AppleSpell  [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation added to connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]]
default 09:12:06.328862 +0200   AppleSpell  [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation removed from connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [YES]]
default 09:12:06.328930 +0200   AppleSpell  [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Removed XPC connection, no remaining operations]
default 09:12:06.328985 +0200   AppleSpell  [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [[CalAgentLinkQueueStatusOperation] operation finished: [0x7fae096ab740].  Total time in microseconds: [737] us.]
default 09:12:06.903604 +0200   Spotlight   [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Starting operation: [CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]].]
default 09:12:06.903710 +0200   Spotlight   [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Created new XPC connection]
default 09:12:06.903964 +0200   Spotlight   [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation added to connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]]
default 09:12:06.904356 +0200   Spotlight   [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation removed from connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [YES]]
default 09:12:06.904453 +0200   Spotlight   [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Removed XPC connection, no remaining operations]
default 09:12:06.904534 +0200   Spotlight   [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [[CalAgentLinkQueueStatusOperation] operation finished: [0x6000044baf80].  Total time in microseconds: [767] us.]
default 09:12:07.327893 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Starting operation: [CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]].]
default 09:12:07.327967 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Starting operation: [CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]].]
default 09:12:07.328080 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Starting operation: [CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]].]
default 09:12:07.328135 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Created new XPC connection]
default 09:12:07.328184 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Starting operation: [CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]].]
default 09:12:07.328233 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation added to connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]]
default 09:12:07.328587 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation added to connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]]
default 09:12:07.328749 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation added to connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]]
default 09:12:07.329086 +0200   suggestd    [com.apple.calendar.agentLink.log] [Operation added to connection: CalendarFoundationWrapper, Running queue found: [NO]]
```

Comment: I still don't know what it was doing but a restart helped.